`static_cast<const bool&>` with `explicit operator bool`
Consider the following:

struct C {
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {

    C c;

    auto b = static_cast<const bool &>(c);

    return 0;

}

Clang++ 18 compiles fine, G++ 14 says:
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:14: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘C’ to type ‘const bool&’
   12 |     auto b = static_cast<const bool &>(c);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

See on Compiler Explorer.
This incompatibility arose in my code because Catch2 test macros use that kind of static_cast under the hood and it fails with a custom type with an explicit operator bool, but only with G++.
It seems to me that since a bool temporary can bind to a const bool &, this should be allowed.
Who's right here, following the standard?

It looks to me like auto b = static_cast<const bool&>(static_cast<bool>(c)); should be needed

Or auto b = static_cast<const bool&>(c.operator bool());

Or even Or auto b = static_cast<const bool&>(!!c);  Because of the explicit on the explicit operator bool() const member function.

TL;DR
Clang is right.
Details:
When you type operator bool()explicit the complete restriction that explicit causes is described here:
[class.conv.fct]/2

A conversion function may be explicit ([dcl.fct.spec]), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization ([dcl.init]).
Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations.

static_cast does not involve assignments, just initializations.  Are the initializations that occur in a static_cast direct or not?
[dcl.init.general]/15:

The initialization that occurs

(15.1) for an initializer that is a parenthesized expression-list or a braced-init-list,
(15.2) for a new-initializer ([expr.new]),
(15.3) in a static_cast expression ([expr.static.cast]),
(15.4) in a functional notation type conversion ([expr.type.conv]), and
(15.5) in the braced-init-list form of a condition

is called direct-initialization.

the standard explicitly states that initialization that occurs in a static_cast expression is a direct-initialization.
So explicit cannot restrict how operator bool() works in a static_cast.  (ok, it could restrict it if we ended up having a concept restriction that queried assignment properties of the right hand side type with being assigned to a bool, but I'm not even sure HOW I'd write that!)
What is going on when you static cast to a reference?
[expr.static.cast]/4:

If T is a reference type, the effect is the same as performing the declaration and initialization T t(E);
for some invented temporary variable t ([dcl.init]) and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

This initialization, by [dcl.init.general]/15, is a direct-initialization, so operator bool()const explicit is permitted to be used.
I don't think it is in doubt that
struct foo {
  operator bool()const{return true;}
};
foo f;
bool const& b = f;

is perfectly legal; so, clang is right, the other compilers are in error.
...
Apparently there is doubt that bool const& b = f; is legal when f has a non-explicit operator bool()const.  So here is my evidence it is legal:
bool const& b = f; is legal due to [dcl.init]/5.1.2 which permits binding to a const-lvalue-ref-to-T from an object that can be converted to an rvalue-to-T.
bool const& b = f; is safe to due "temporary materialization" and reference lifetime extension causing the materialized temporary to last as long as the const-lvalue-ref-to-T does.
Note that the use of = here would not be legal if the operator bool was explicit, it would have to be bool const& b(f); if f has an explicit operator bool; however, this section merely exists to point out that without explicit there is no problem.  Prior logic shows that explicit does not cause a problem, as the initialization in a static_cast is, well, an explicit one.

[dcl.init.general]/15 is being miss-interpreted. The result of static_cast is subject to direct initialization, if the result is not a reference; The input is unaffected. In other words usingstatic_cast is akin to a function call; the only exception being a call on a prvalue or xvalue. Your interpretation defeats the purpose of explicit keyword in preventing unintentional conversions. G++ looks to be exhibiting the correct behavior.

@Red.Wave Initialization in a static cast is direct-initialization, period, by the standard text.  If you disagree with the standard, sure, no skin off my back.  But you provide zero evidence that that isn't what the standard says.  There is no "if the result is not a reference" clause I can see.  "The input is unaffacted" is also an irrelevant sentence as far as I can tell?  It is not akin to a function call, because it is direct initialization, and function calls are not direct-initialization.

I was a bit uncertain about that last example and started thinking about when it is and is not legal to bind a reference to dangling temporary and then not use the reference - until I remembered that the binding of bool const& b extends the lifetime of the materialized temporary, so none of that matters. Might be worth a brief note.

So let's deprecate the explicit key word for ever. Because that's supposed to do nothing. And let static_cast magically circumvent every possible measure against unintended conversions? That's certainly bringing more safety too the language. The current wording in the standard text is defect, IMO this is a proper case for DR. I wish someone from the committee could leave a responce; the question is tagged as language-lawyer after all.

@Red.Wave I think your problem is you don't know that static_cast is an explicit conversion?  explicit operator bool()const is supposed to defend against a+b being "a converts to bool, which converts to an integer, and then you add b to that integer".  It is not supposed to defend against cases where someone asks for a bool.  I'm not sure why you think static_cast<bool const&>(smart_pointer) should be banned?  It is pretty harmless.  And you are explicitly asking for smart_pointer to be converted to a bool.

@aschepler I hope anyone plubming this far into the depths of C++ quirks knows about temporary materialization and reference lifetime extension...  But maybe that is the source of people's fear of casting to a bool const&?

@aschepler Added a bunch of words covering bool const& b = f;

The explicitness of static_cast only applies to the last level cast. static_cast<bool>(c) is prefectly legal. But the cast in question requires another explicit cast before last level cast: auto const& b=static_cast<bool>(c);

@Red.Wave I mean, I provided standard quotes; as far as I can tell, you are inventing stuff that isn't what the standard says.  static_cast<bool const&> is one direct-initialization, not two casts, and explicit simply restricts the cast to be only used during direct-initialization.  And taking a prvalue of bool and binding to a const bool& is not a separate conversion; it is just how references bind to temporaries.

So the definition of direct initialization has extended to cover such cases in a peculiar way. Reading the standard literature is difficult. I need better interpretations on how static_cast is performed.

@Red.Wave static_cast<X>(expr) is literally equivalent to X x(expr); with the note that x represents a prvalue not a value.  Y const& x(obj); when obj has an explicit operator Y instantiates a temporary Y then binds it and lifetime extends it to x.  explicit blocks Y const& x = obj;, but when you do Y const& x(obj); that is the exact syntax that is supposed to be considered explicit (and cases like static cast which are equivalent).

So explicit construction discards qualifiers, if exact match is not found? i.e. it considers partially qualified and unqualified conversions at lower priority? Is this part of direct initialization process?

@Red.Wave I have linked the relevant section in the answer.  https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#ref-5.1.2 if you want a repeat link.  I encourage you to use the [ask question] to learn more about how conversions work in C++ instead of in a random comment thread.

tldr; The program is well-formed as this is direct-initialization and explicit conversion functions can be used in direct-initialization.

First note that static_cast<const bool &>(c) is direct-intiaization. So we move onto dcl.init#16:

The semantics of initializers are as follows.
The destination type is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression.
If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
If the destination type is a reference type, see [dcl.init.ref].

So we move onto dcl.init.ref:

A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:

Otherwise, if the initializer expression

has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an rvalue of type “cv3 T3” or an lvalue of function type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (see [over.match.ref]),

then the initializer expression in the first case and the converted expression in the second case is called the converted initializer.
If the converted initializer is a prvalue, let its type be denoted by T4; the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied, considering the type of the prvalue to be “cv1 T4” ([conv.qual]).
In any case, the reference binds to the resulting glvalue (or to an appropriate base class subobject).



(emphasis mine)
This means that the initializer c is converted to a bool prvalue and then the reference is bound to the xvalue produced from the temporary materialization.
Note also that explicit conversion functions can be used in direct initialization contexts as per class.conv.fct:

A conversion function may be explicit ([dcl.fct.spec]), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization ([dcl.init]).
Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations.

So the program is well-formed.

There is no "usually" - the only restriction explicit does is "can only be used in direct-initialization".  And initialization during static_cast is explicitly guaranteed to be direct-initialization.  So within a static_cast, all initializations permit use of explicit conversion operators.  You'd have to find a user-defined conversion not used for initialization used during static_cast for the explicit to make a difference; I can't see one?  (and even then, as it is part of a direct-initialization, it being legal is a strong argument)

Thanks to everyone! I see you both agree on the result (Clang is right) but I see different explanations. I really cannot reason by myself about who has the right explanation, to mark the accepted answer. Have you reached a consensus?

@NicolaGigante Both explanations are actually same and right. My answer just has extra dcl.init.ref to be complete. Otherwise, the explanations are the same. You're welcome.
